# "NameError: name 'mousex' is not defined" in another function

Tags: python, global-variables, nameerror

I'm making a Rummy card game but having a few problems around `mouse[]`, `cardx[]`, `cardy[]`.
I have all variables globalled at the beginning of program, but when in subroutines `()` it seems to forget what they are.

[image]

```
def image(img,imgx,imgy):   
    screen.blit(img, (imgx,imgy))

def getmouse():
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=mouse[0],mouse[1]
    print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0]) #works fine here

def movableimgs():
    getmouse()
    for d in range(1,6):
        print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0])  #Error here nameError: name 'mousex'is not defined
        if cardx[d]<mousex>cardx[d]+71 and cardy[d]<mousey>cardy[d]+96:
            drag=1
        if click[0]==0:
            drag=0
```

I am having problems with the `click[]` too. It works in `getmouse()` but after it comes back from `getmouse()` it doesn't work. I am having trouble with the `cardx[]` and `cardy[]` too. I have all global at beginning of program.

Answer (score 1):

**Global and Local variable**

from the code/function

```
def getmouse():
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=mouse[0],mouse[1]
    print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0]) #works fine here
```

you set the `mouse`, `click`, `mousex`, `mousey` as `local` variable, you need `global` command to access the variable that's set in function, so your `getmouse`

So your code will be like this

```
def getmouse():
    global mouse, click, mousex, mousey
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=mouse[0],mouse[1]
    print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0]) #works fine here
```

But that is not effective way, so you should change the `getmouse` function to

```
def getmouse():
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=mouse[0],mouse[1]
    print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0]) #works fine here
    globals().update(locals()) #this is the effective way, and pythonic
```

So your full code is

```
def image(img,imgx,imgy):   
    screen.blit(img, (imgx,imgy))

def getmouse():
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=mouse[0],mouse[1]
    print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0]) #works fine here
    globals().update(locals())

def movableimgs():
    getmouse()
    for d in range(1,6):
        print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0])  #Error here nameError: name 'mousex'is not defined
        if cardx[d]<mousex>cardx[d]+71 and cardy[d]<mousey>cardy[d]+96:
            drag=1
        if click[0]==0:
            drag=0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Local variables

`mousex`, `mousey` and `click` are local variables in the callee function `getmouse`.

To use it in the caller function `movableimgs`, you should return the values in the callee function and then unpack the values into variables in the caller function.

```py
def getmouse():
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=mouse[0],mouse[1]
    print("Mouse x:y",mousex,mousey, "Mouse Click",click[0])
    return mousex, mousey, click  # Return the values

def movableimgs():
    mousex, mousey, click = getmouse()  # Unpack the values into variables
    ...
```

## Global variables

> problems around `mouse[]`, `cardx[]`, `cardy[]`.

> problems with the `click[]` ... I have all global at beginning of program.

To assign to global variables `mouse` and `click` in a function, you need to declare them as `global`.

```py
def getmouse():
    global mouse, click  # Declare global variables
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    ...
```